# Is it possible to retrieve the value from textbox before submission?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have a `textbox` where users will input their mobile numbers.

```
<input type="number" name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber" runat="server" />
```

I also have a `dialog box` where I used it as a confirmation when the users click on the `submit` button.

```
var answer = confirm("The number you have entered is <%= confirmNumber %>.\nPlease verify if the number you have entered is correct.")

if (!answer) {
    return false;
}
```

My expected output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFafE.png) where __________ is supposed to be the `value` of the `textbox`.
(Apparently I don't have enough points to embed pictures yet?)

What I want to do is to retrieve the `value` from the `textbox` and replace the underscores in the `dialog box` with it.

Here is my C# attempt to retrieve the `value` from the `textbox`:

```
string confirmNumber = mobileNumber.Value;
```

I think that the C# code can only retrieve the `value` after the user has submitted? I am not really sure. Please help.

Comment: JQuery is your friend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show value that is entered on client side in textbox you can use javascript which you already have to show value to user. You have to use the ClientID of input to get its html element in javascript.

```
number = document.getElementById("<%=mobileNumber.ClientID%>").value;
var answer = confirm("The number you have entered is" + number  + ".\nPlease verify if the number you have entered is correct.")
```

Comment: I'm a little new to jQuery/JavaScript, so pardon me. Anyhow, this works perfectly! Thank you so much!